# Wifi Tx rate in airport and speedtest cli upload/download speeds are drastically different

Tags: network, wifi, airport

When I run `airport -I` or `opt` click my wifi icon, it says my wifi Tx rate is around 700 Mbps, but when I run the speedtest-cli command, it says my upload speed is 20 Mbit/s and download speed is 30 Mbit/s. Shouldn't the upload speed and Tx rate be the same thing? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tx rate is the speed of connection between your computer and the WiFi; this is not the same as the speed of your network connection provided by your ISP. So you might have a high speed in your local network, but accessing the internet has lower speed limited by your internet plan (which is what speedtest-cli tests for as it establishes a connection with a server somewhere else).

If you want to test LAN speed, use `iperf` on local devices.

Comment: I have a 1Gbps connection from my ISP and speed tests on both my routers show ~800Mbps. My RSSI is -50 dBM and Noise is -90 dBM. Do you know how I can figure out where the bottle neck is?

Comment: @Matt D Plug in your computer to ethernet and see if you are on 1000 mbps protocol. If not, the problem might be on your switch?

Comment: What switch? I'm on a home network.

Comment: I don't really know networking, so I'm probably wrong (esp. my vocabulary), but I guess you have a router (used to be modem) which connects to the internet, a switch which connects to the router, and all of your (ethernet-connected) devices connect to the switch using ethernet cables which go through/in your wall. Your Wi-Fi serves as a wireless switch, and it is also connected to your switch. So the switch provides the local ethernet by connecting multiple devices. If the switch operates on 100mbps protocol, then it might be the bottleneck.